# PhpWord CloneBlock and character limit

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using PHPWord, and I have an error with cloneBlock() function at a TemplateProcessor.

I wrap a table and a pagebreak into ${cloneme} ... ${/cloneme}. If i use this, it works well :

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('template.docx');
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', $nbjour-1);
```

I can have as many pages as days. My problem is, if I want to put text after the ${/cloneme}, I got a .docx file with only one table, not duplicated, and still the ${cloneme}...${/cloneme} tags written.

But it's not just "text". If I wrote 5 lines, it will duplicate. If I wrote 7, it'll bug. Same thing with a table (still after the ${/cloneme}). 6 rows are ok, but 8 will bug.

I'm tilted, someone can figure out where I'm wrong?

I give you 2 images, first one working, second none.

Working :
[image: Working]
Not working :
[image: Not working]